# using a function from another wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, shortcode

I want to create an if statement inorder to show if the weather is below or above zero.

I am using The PRO version of awesome weather widget Wordpress plugin to display the weather. The plugin got a couple of functions to use: https://halgatewood.com/docs/plugins/awesome-weather-widget/pro-functions-grab-weather-data

When I use my code I am getting a error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   get_awesome_weather_widget() in ...

**My code:**

```
function check_weather() {
    $t = get_awesome_weather_widget('wakita, OK');

if ($t < "0") {
    echo "<p>The weather is above 0 degrees!</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>The weather is NOT below 0 degrees!</p>";
}
}

add_shortcode('dronevejr', 'check_weather');
```

Comment: Is the awesome weather plugin active?

Comment: @cabrerahector yes it is :)

Comment: That's odd. The function should be available then. Obviously it's not, otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error message. Where are you registering your shortcode? functions.php? Custom plugin?

Comment: @cabrerahector the code from my post is placed in functions.php in my child theme and I'm then using the shortcode [dronevejr] on a Wordpress page.

Comment: Sounds about right. Since the Pro version of the plugin isn't publicly available (unless you buy it of course) it's a little difficult to help you debug the issue (this is the "problem" with non-open-source software.) Have you tried reaching out to the developer already?